# Does a run on empty archives add counter on Datasucker?

Tags: android-netrunner

I've got a [Datasucker](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/01008). Does a run on empty archives without ice counts as "successful run on a central server"? In other words, if the corp does not have an ice on archives (maybe empty, maybe without face-down cards) do I add counter on the Datasucker for a click?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does a run on empty archives without ice counts as "successful run on a central server"?

Yes it does. The server is empty but it's available for running as usual.

Answer (score 2):

Datasucker only cares if the run was successful, not if you accessed cards. Runs on an empty archives give sucker tokens, can be used for security testing. There are things that can prevent these effects notably [Crisium Grid](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/06048).